# definability and algebraicity over canonical base

Tags: model-theory

This question assumes some familiarity with basic stability theory.
We work in a saturated model of a stable theory eliminating imaginaries.
If $a \in \text{dcl}(C,b)$, then $a\in\text{acl}(\text{Cb}(a,b/C ),b)$ by forking calculus.
My question is if in fact $a\in\text{dcl}(\text{Cb}(a,b/C ),b)$?

I can prove it in the case when the ambient theory is totally trivial:
Suppose the formula $\varphi(x,b,c)$ witnesses that $a \in \text{dcl}(C,b)$.
Suppose that $\sigma$ is an automorphism such that $\sigma(\text{Cb}(a,b/C ))=\text{Cb}(a,b/C )$ and $\sigma(b)=b$. We have to show that $\sigma(a)=a$.
Note that $p_1=\text{tp}(a,b/C)$ and $p_2=\text{tp}(\sigma(a),b/\sigma(C))$ are parallel, i.e. have a common nonforking extension $p\in S(C\cup \sigma(C))$. Let $(a',b')$ be a realisation of $p$.
Note that:

- $b$ is independent from $C$ over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C )$
- $b$ is independent from $\sigma(C)$ over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C )$

Total triviality implies that $b$ is independent from $C \cup \sigma(C)$ over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C )$. Since the type of $b$ over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C )$ is stationary, it follows that $b'$ and $b$ have the same type over $C\cup \sigma(C)$. Hence there is $a''$ such that $(a'',b)$ realises $p$. Then

- $(a'',b)$ realises $p_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\varphi(a'',b,c)$ $\Rightarrow$  $a''=a$ and $\varphi(\sigma(a''),b,\sigma(c))$
- $(a'',b)$ realises $p_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\varphi(a'',b,\sigma(c))$

Hence $\sigma(a)=\sigma(a'')=a''=a$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is just stationarity (if the following is correct?):

Let $\varphi(x,b,c)$ be witnessing that $a\in\text{dcl}(C,b)$.
Suppose that $\sigma$ is an automorphism such that $\sigma(b)=b$ and $\sigma(\text{Cb}(a,b/C))=\text{Cb}(a,b/C)$.
We know that
$a\in\text{acl}(\text{Cb}(a,b/C),b)$, hence

(i) $\sigma(a)\in\text{acl}(\text{Cb}(a,b/C),b)$

We have that $b$ is independent from $C$ over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C)$, hence by (i) we have that

(ii) $(\sigma(a),b)$ is independent from $C$ over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C)$.

But $(a,b)$ and $(\sigma(a),b)$ have the same type over $\text{Cb}(a,b/C)$ and this type is stationary. Hence (ii) implies that $(a,b)$ and $(\sigma(a),b)$ have the same type over $C$. Therefore $\varphi(\sigma(a),b,c)$ holds and this implies $\sigma(a)=a$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your assumptions. Take $a\in\text{dcl}(b\mathfrak{C})$. Assume that $a\not\in\text{dcl}(\text{Cb}(a,b/\mathfrak{C}), b)$. Then there exists some $a'$ distinct from $a$ and they both realize the same algebraic formula over $(\text{Cb}(a,b/\mathfrak{C}), b)$.

**If $a, a'$ have the same orbit over $(\text{Cb}(a,b/\mathfrak{C}), b)$** and assume that $(\text{Cb}(a,b/\mathfrak{C}), b)$ is small (should hold when T is stable), then there is an automorphism $\sigma$ over $($Cb$(a,b/\mathfrak{C}), b)$ sending $a$ to $a'$. Since $\sigma$ fixes Cb$(a,b/\mathfrak{C})$, it must fix tp$(a,b/\mathfrak{C})$ by the definition of canonical basis, which means that
$$\text{tp}(a,b/\mathfrak{C})=\text{tp}(\sigma(a),\sigma(b)/\mathfrak{C})=\text{tp}(a',b/\mathfrak{C}).$$
It follows that tp$(a/b\mathfrak{C})=\text{tp}(a'/b\mathfrak{C})$. By $a\in\text{dcl}(b\mathfrak{C})$, we have $a=a'$.

**Assume that $a,a'$ are in different orbits over $(\text{Cb}(a,b/\mathfrak{C}),b)$**. Use the **fact**: for a small set $A\subseteq\mathfrak{C}$, the orbit of $a$ under the action of $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{C}/A)$ is singleton iff $a\in\text{dcl}(A)$.

Proof of the fact: For the nontrivial direction '$\Rightarrow$' of this fact, note that if $a$ and $a'$ are in different orbit, the proof I knew  was to say that tp$(a/A)$ has two realizations (by a small set of formulas), which is inconsistent by saturation, so it results in a formula witnessing $a\in\text{dcl}(A)$.

It was quite surprising when I think about the fact in this direction: why cannot $a,a'$ be realizations of the same algebraic formula, while they both have orbit as singletons. It turned out that saturation really yields a formula defining them separately.

Comment: If the orbit of $a$ over $B$ is just $\{a\}$, then $a$ is in $\mathrm{dcl}(B)$. So you only have to deal with the case that $a$ and $a'$ are in the same orbit.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you. That's right. I knew this result, but did not realize that it is actually suprising...

Comment: Perhaps when you put it this way, it's less surprising: if $a$ is algebraic over $B$, then $\mathrm{tp}(a/B)$ is isolated. So when you pick a formula witnessing the algebricity, you might as well pick one $\varphi(x,b)$ isolating the type of $a$ over $B$. Then the set of realizations of $\varphi(x,b)$ is the orbit of $a$ over $B$.

Comment: In your answer, is $\mathfrak{C}$ supposed to be the monster model? I think your argument works in that case, but not in the case when $C$ is an arbitrary small set: $\sigma$ fixing $\mathrm{Cb}(a,b/C)$ only implies that $\tp(\sigma(a),\sigma(b)/\sigma(C))$ and $\tp(a,b/C)$ are parallel, not equal (in fact, they are over different sets of parameters!).